# Should I use client-side frameworks like Ember or React for a non SPA?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, reactjs, single-page-application

Our application shows pages with 90% static content. Clicking a link always generates another similar page. In fact, with the exception of a proposed ticker of some sort, nothing will change on the page once its rendered.

Recently, I've been asked to evaluate either EmberJS or ReactJS as the framework to use in our next version. We do have quite the logic on the server-side, and we can render templates much faster on the server, and cache the resulting HTML.

My question is: since my app is NOT an SPA, is there any benefit at all for client-side MVC? Or should I just handle everything (templates, routing, state management) on the server side?

Comment: My **opinion**: Please dont use a client side MVC, it sounds like a server-side solution is a solid fit and my educated guess is the only reason you've been asked to evaluate Ember and React is that someone with a tie read an article about them on Gartner.

Comment: Try asking on IRC or a message board.  This question is off topic here.

Comment: Why exactly is a question about programming off topic on a programming question board? I've been asking and answering questions here for years, and I didn't know that if my q did contain code it would be voted down. I'm not asking for opinions, but for a professional, to-the-point answer.

Comment: But you're not going to get a professional to-the-point answer on such a question from anyone who doesn't know the full requirements of your application. And even from someone who possesses that information any answer you get will be based on opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing will change on the page once its rendered probably a client side MVC framework is not what you are looking for. They are designed for rich web apps, these frameworks dynamically load resources to the page as necessary, as a response to user actions or route changes. In a SPA application the page does not reload during user interaction.

If you render a diff page every time a user clicks a link everything will be restarted, you can still implement an "hybrid" app and use these frameworks, they are not SPA exclusive, we have accomplished this functionality multiple times.

SPA is a hugely concept to grasp but you usually adopt libraries to handle aspects that are essential to your app, but seems that right now you do not have one.

I suggest to read this article from John Papa.

http://www.johnpapa.net/pageinspa/

Thanks